# React Filter array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I Have an array of object like this:

```
 export const SITE_MAP = [
{
 label: "Home",
 path: "/homepage",
 expansion: [],
},
{
label: "user",
expansion: [
  {
    label: "Catalogue",
    icon: "account",
    path: "pat_to",
    permission: "yes",
    items: []
```

I need to create a new array myHome which contains all the objects with permission yes.
How can i filter the SITE_MAP and assign it to the new array Myhome?

Thank you!

Comment: Assignment in JS uses `=` and `.filter` filters arrays.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: I've changed my code. It kind of answer my question but the issue is that i cannot access permission

Answer (score 2):

```js
const SITE_MAP = [{
    label: "Schemes",
    icon: "control_camera",
    path: "control",
    permission: "yes",
    items: []
 },{
    label: "Schemes",
    icon: "control_camera",
    path: "control",
    permission: "no",
    items: []
  }
 ]
 
 const myHome = SITE_MAP.filter(el => el.permission === 'yes')
 
 console.log(myHome)
```

Comment: (this question is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: i modified my array... i've tried your suggestion but it just store the label home and not the child

Comment: HI @Marco I just showed you the way to achieve what you are expecting, Now you need to go that path by yourself :) Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` method to filter retrieve only Object which you need.

```js
const SITE_MAP = [
  {
      label: "Schemes",
      icon: "control_camera",
      path: "control",
      permission: "yes",
      items: []
   }
]

const myHome = SITE_MAP.filter(site =>{
  return site.permission === "yes";
});

console.log(myHome);
```